# PHP : Change Array key

Tags: php, foreach, codeigniter-3

I have an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 8
)
```

I want change my array like this:

```
Array
(
    ['present'] => 2
    ['absent'] => 8
)
```

Comment: Whats the basis? if index 2 = 'present'? 1 = 'absent'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Change Array Integer Index to Key String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454471/php-change-array-integer-index-to-key-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as this

```
$array = array(2 => 2, 1 => 8);

$output['present'] = $array[2];
$output['absent'] = $array[1];

print_r($output);
```

If it's a multi-dimensional array of absents and presents

```
$array = array(
    array(2 => 2, 1 => 8),
    array(2 => 3, 1 => 7)
);

foreach ($array as $value) {
   $output[] = array('present' => $value[2], 'absent' => $value[1]);
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: What if the first array has 1000 records ? Try to make it reusable Code..

Comment: Thanks its working...

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = array_combine(array('present', 'absent'), 
                array_values(array(2 => 2, 1 => 8)));
print_r($res);
```